# RMI client method call

Tags: java, compiler-errors, rmi

I'm new to RMI and trying to apply the following to the project I'm working on.
Does this piece of code `Naming.lookup...... theWork.newCalculator();` always need to be in `main` method?
Can I call `myCalculator` outside `main` method?
When I tried, I'm getting `myCalculator cannot be resolved` error.
Below example calls `myCalculator` in `main` so it works. How do I make `myCalculator.plus(arg)` available in another method?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{

        try{


            CalculatorFactory theWorks =     (CalculatorFactory)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:13456/CalculationsAnon");
            Calculator myCalculator = theWorks.newCalculator();

            System.out.println("I have a calculator");

            int val = 0;
            myCalculator.clear();
            BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            for(;;)
            {
                System.out.println(": "+val+":");
                System.out.print("Command>");
                String s = (bin.readLine().trim());

                if(s.equals("+")){

                    System.out.print("Value>");
                    int arg = 0;
                    s=(bin.readLine().trim());
                    arg = Integer.parseInt(s);
                    val = myCalculator.plus(arg);

                }

                // more codes here
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined the myCalculator object as a local variable inside your main method which is why if you try to reference it outside you get cannot be resolved error.

Did you try defining the myCalculator object reference outside your main method like this:-

```
private static Calculator myCalculator = null;

public static void main(String [] args)
{

        try{


            CalculatorFactory theWorks =     (CalculatorFactory)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:13456/CalculationsAnon");
            myCalculator = theWorks.newCalculator();

           // You rest of the code here
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does this piece of code "Naming.lookup...... theWork.newCalculator();" always need to be in main method?

No.

> Can I call myCalculator outside main method?

Yes, as long as you have access to the `theWorks` variable.

> When I tried, I'm getting `myCalculator cannot be resolved` error.

This is a compile error. The variable mentioned isn't in scope. It really has nothing to do with RMI at all, just a common progamming error.

> Below example calls myCalculator in main so it works. How do I make myCalculator.plus(arg) available in another method?

Do the lookup in that method, or store the result of the main method's lookup into a static or instance variable instead of a local variable.